# Linked in folders in SP2010

Tags: folder, content-organizer

I am currently re-structuring a team site trying to consolidate the existing information. I have several repositories (folders) which content could be duplicated (maybe a couple of Business Process Documents).

I was wondering if there is any function that would allow me to create a link or reference within a folder to address the user to another folder where they could find that document.

This would help us to maintain the site tidy and organised and prevent that the repeated document is not updated adequately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the management of content types in the document library.  Add the Link to Document content type to the library.  Then in the folder of your choosing, select the Link to Document from the New menu and point it to the file you'd like.  Rinse/repeat as nessary.  (Steps above taken from memory of SP 2007, exact process for 2010 may be different).